# Resolving duplicate mutex lock in Go

Tags: multithreading, go, mutex

I have a bunch of functions in a Go program that work on a struct that uses a mutex to manage concurrent access to its functions.

Some of these functions, that operate on specific data, need locks and thereby use mutex.Lock() to get hold of a mutex that manages the access to that data. Today I encountered an issue when two of these locking methods call each other. As soon as mutex.Lock() is called a second time it blocks - of course.

The problem I am facing is very similar to this code: http://play.golang.org/p/rPARZsordI

Is there any best-practise in Go on how to solve this issue? As far as I know recursive locks are not available in Go.

Comment: Have a single method that locks, writes and unlocks and let all other methods use that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a design flaw of your system. You should factor out the part that you need both locked and unlocked. E.g. if what you do is

```
func (t *Thing) A() { t.Lock(); defer t.Unlock(); t.foo(); t.B() }
func (t *Thing) B() { t.Lock(); defer t.Unlock(); t.bar() }
```

then what you should do instead is

```
func (t *Thing) A() { t.Lock(); defer t.Unlock(); t.foo(); t.b() }
func (t *Thing) B() { t.Lock(); defer t.Unlock(); t.b() }
func (t *Thing) b() { t.bar() }
```

Comment: Thanks. I just refactored the code to lock closer to the actual data access and this saved the issue. Seems like I was too deep in the code to see that obvious mistake.

Comment: I would rather have `b()` does the locking.  It seems that, from your example, `t.bar()` is the resource that is concurrently sensitive, not `A()` nor `B()`

Comment: So can be `t.foo()`. It's about composability, cases where you need to do `t.foo()` and `t.bar()` in one "transaction". Lowercase methods are unexported so they're not supposed to be used only outside the package anyway.